# How to append some data directly to a file with node.js?

Tags: node.js

Let's say we have:

- a file `data.json` or `data.txt` with this content: `{"data":[]}`
- and an array of paths: `["C:\\path1", "C:\\path2", "C:\\path3"]`

### Question

How would we append the array of paths into this file with node.js data stream (or whatnot) so that we get this in the end:

```
{"data":["C:\\path1", "C:\\path2", "C:\\path3"]}
```

### Code

```
let filePath = 'C:\test\data.json'
let paths = ["C:\\path1", "C:\\path2", "C:\\path3"]

for (let index = 0; index < paths.length; index++) {
  // ... streaming paths to the file one by one
}
```

I cannot put `paths` in the file without a loop - in my project I have `walkdir(drive, options, (path) => {})` instead of `for` loop. It also returns paths one by one like the above `for` loop, it's just for demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is JSON, you can't actually append to the file. You have to read out the entire document, parse the JSON to a POJO, make your changes, stringify the JSON, and write it back.

```
import { readFile, writeFile } from 'fs';

readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw new Error(err);

  const json = JSON.parse(data);

  paths.forEach(path => json.data.push(path));

  writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(json), err => { /* handle err */ });
});
```

If it was a plaintext file, you could do an append by writing to it and setting the `flag` option to `a` (for append).

```
writeFile(filePath, { flag: 'a' }, 'text to append');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know whether the `writeFile` as efficient  as `createWriteStream`? The paths array is 300 MB in size, I'm not sure which method is better to use in this case

Comment: If you are doing the JSON version, then probably `writeFile` will be probably best if you write to the file only once. If you are writing it repeatedly in between, then `createWriteStream` may edge it out. They should be pretty similar in performance though.

Comment: Yeah, I need to write each `path` one by one on every iteration of the loop so that it goes directly to the file without staying in ram. Thanks for the info

Comment: If you have to continuously stream it because you are worried about losing the data or something, I would probably recommend writing each record to a plaintext file where they are just newline delimited, and then have a different process that reads that file and converts it to JSON periodically. It could get rather process intensive to continually write out an entire 300MB file depending how quickly you need to process things.

Comment: I think I should just write it to a txt file instead and parse it when I need the access. It looks like it takes almost no time to parse the string from txt into a json